# Auto inject framework utilities into $scope

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

IMHO, framework should do the heavy lifting. Dependency Injection(DI) is a great feature in ng. But, it looks ugly.  Same thing applies to DI.

Why not  inject $scope with framework utilities $http, $routeProvider etc once module.config is called.

Not sure if this would ever be possible?
What we do now:

```
  phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.phones = data;
  });

  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
});
```

VS

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.$http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
    ...
});
```

ng folks, is this something you already have on your radar to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that this is a good approach, $scope is intended to have the relationship between the controller and the view, if you inject everything in the $scope, why would you need the controller? I think this goes againts the MVC principles.

Comment: I am OK to have another variable like   `phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope, $utils) {`. What I am asking is the framework should set the right context and the controller should do bare minimum.

Comment: I Agree, but if you get all utillities in the scope, you may be getting dependencies injected that you wont even use, lets say you get $http always injected to $scope, What if you never use it? You may be having unessesary things in your $scope.

Comment: Well, angular has so many functions:[docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/function). But, developers most commonly use `angular.module`. Similarly, it would up to the developer to choose which service to use. I could use DI for business/app related factories.  Thanks for sharing your thoughts!